# 301 redirection to changed urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to change the domain name of my site and I will use permanent redirection 301. I found that this setup on .htaccess will do the job:

```bash
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

But I also need to change all urls structure from http://www.new-example.com/old/this-is-url1.html to http://www.new-example.com/this-is-url1.html.

Rule must effect only urls with directory `old` on their alias: www.new-example.com/old/...

And redirect them to urls without directory `old`: www.new-example.com/

Can you please show me what redirect rule I must use on .htaccess to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your shown code with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:old/?)?(.*)$ http://new-example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: this code works perfectly for changing all my links with "old" directory, but i also need to change all links with new domain name. Is it right to use both codes, my first code for domain name redirection and your code for my specific case?

Comment: Yes this one is working perfectly! I use: RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:old/)?(.*)$ http://new-example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

Comment: This code works perfect! I try to use rewriterule without www to have all my links without www  and is working perfect , except the case scenario when i enter the new domain with www. When i enter new domain name with www it doesnt redirect it to a non www.

Comment: yes that will work perfect. What do i have to change?

Comment: If the directory "old" without "/" it remains on the url. www.example.com/old/.... is redirecting,but www.example.com/old is not

Comment: Now www.example.com/old is redirecting right but www.example.com/old/test gives new-example.comtest and not new-example.com/test

Comment: No that's wrong. `http://example.com/old/test` gets redirected to `http://new-example.com/new/test` you have old cache probably or some other problem

Comment: yes you are right! Is working! I'm really thank you! Great answers!

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help. This code works great for removing the "old" folder from redirected urls. Can you please show me how to rename this folder name and not remove it? I want "www.example.com/old"  to give me  "new-example.com/new-old". Thank you

Comment: I already post a new question:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090241/301-redirect-to-new-domain-and-new-name-folder   Perhaps you can help me on this.