# 301 redirect to new domain and new name folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm going to change my domain name but also need to change and one folder name on url structure. I want "www.example.com/name" to become "new-example.com/new-name".

I have this code for .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:name/?)?(.*)$ http://new-example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

but this code remove "name" folder on redirected links. How can i change folder name and not remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^name(/.*)?$ http://new-example.com/new-name$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: This code redirect every url to "new-example.com/new-name"  and not only urls that have "name" folder. For example if i enter  www.example.com/name2  i get  new-example.com/new-name/name2

Comment: Now only urls that contain "name" folder are redirected. If i use for example www.example.com/name2 i get www.example.com/name2 with no redirection at all.

Comment: No i need to change only urls that contain "name" folder to "name2" folder. Redirect all urls from old domain name to new domain name, and if there is "name" folder on url structure change it to "name2".

Comment: Thats it! Yes that works exactly as i need it! Only urls with "name" folder redirected on urls with "name2". You are for sure a mod-rewrite expert. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^name/(.*)$ http://new-example.com/new-name/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```